# Place Name Spelling

Tags: discussion, feature-request, place-names-and-spelling

I noticed that Moher was misspelled twice in a post, which could make searches a nuisance, so I attempted to correct the two instances, however, I received this message:

> Oops! Your edit couldn't be submitted because:
>
> Edits must be at least 6 characters; is there something else to
>   improve in this post?

The [post is fine](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/1033/irelands-top-places-to-visit-with-a-toddler/1036#1036), any other changes would be tampering for the sake of it.

Place names are particularly important in a Travel forum, I reckon, so it should be possible to make such changes.

Comment: You always can comment the post to point out the error.

Comment: Sure, so when you come to search for that place, will it come up? I do not think so.

Answer (score 6):

I don't think we need to allow small suggested edits. Users with high rep can edit posts as they want, and you always have three things available to do:

1. Flag post to the moderate attention with spell error explanation.
2. Comment out the post to post owner or some user with high rep edit the post.
3. **Mostly preferred** - make great suggested edit! See what can you add to the post. For this exactly post you can simply add a link to the Cliffs of Moher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cliffs_of_Moher), and your edit will be accepted.
4. Earn more reputation to be available to edit other people's posts.

> We don’t run Stack Overflow. The community does.